# Effect of rendering calls on performance

Tags: c++, opengl

Consider a situation ,

Case 1 : I am giving opengl calls to draw the world by drawing all polygons. So all polygons will be drawn according to all objects exist. (Considered all translation rotation).

Case 2 : I will allow only polygons that are in field of view(FOV) of camera to be drawn. So obviously calls for rendering will be reduced. But call for checking if the polygon is in FOV will increase for each polygon.

So my question : **which case(method) is better considering the effect on performance?**

What i think : Since number of calls will double in case 2 (calculating if polygon is in FOV + call for rendering) I think that 2nd case will be slow. If I am incorrect then correct me.

*I have tagged c++ if language matters*

Comment: The answer is a mixture. A check per polygon will be slower than just rendering it anyway. Instead, check per object or create a *bounding volume hierarchy*, drawing batches of geometry that are visible.

Comment: Consider I am drawing a building and half of building is out of FOV and rest can be seen. That's where I am stuck.

Comment: A BVH will allow you to quickly draw things in-view, then applying *occlusion culling* will further remove volumes of geometry occluded by other volumes.

Comment: @jozxyqk occlusion culling is usually done on GPU to avoid running the pixel shader on certain pixels - doing OC on the CPU after VFC is rarely beneficial

Comment: @BeyelerStudios perhaps I'm mixing up terms, but if the camera is in a room with no windows and looking towards a city of rooms, the city is occluded by walls and should be culled. I'm aware of fine grain occlusion culling, e.g. I would say even the early depth test is a form, but I assumed the same term could be used in this context too, where entire groups of objects are not drawn as they are occluded. [For example](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html).

Comment: @jozxyqk hallways and generally [CSG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry)-ed scenes are a beneficial environment for CPU occlusion culling - then there are occlusion queries (usually implemented in tandem on the GPU and CPU), etc... OC is just a very large topic and is always very specific to your application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the way you describe that (checking if each polygon is within FOV), it will almost always be slower - GPU can do it faster. But this idea can be improved by organizing the polygons in some clever data structure, which can quickly cut out large numbers of polygons that are not in the FOV. Examples of these are [octrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree), [R-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree), [BSP-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning) and many other.

Comment: "GPU can do it faster."  GPU detects that the polygon is in view or not?

Comment: @Fennekin sure. OpenGL clips input polygons so that they lie inside the view volume. https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Clipping

Comment: That saves me from coding bounds for each object. I will let GPU handle that

Comment: @Fennekin if it becomes a bottleneck, spatial data structures I mentioned will save you!

Comment: I am not experienced with trees. But if it becomes the last option to resort to I will have to implement it in my program

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to not check for each polygon. You will check for some larger bounding area, typically a bounding box. Doing this check is fast and O(1) in polygons, and will be nearly 100% effective (there's only a few edge positions you can be in to not be culled when you should be).

Therefore, culling is very fast, much faster than rendering all the polys.

Comment: Yes back face culling will surely help. But do u mean that I will have to implement bounding code for each door/window

Comment: @Fennekin: You can produce code that calculates an AABB from an arbitrary set of polygons relatively simply. You can also simply guesstimate it since the exact bounds don't matter that much.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what Puppy posted, but I would like to add something to it. Definitely check if objects are in the FOV using bounding boxes, first. Then, once you know if an object is in the FOV, you should check which polygons on that object are in the FOV, using face normals. There is no point in drawing polygons that no one will ever see.

Comment: @jozxyqk Strictly speaking, enabling culling eliminates polygons based on the winding order, not the normals. Of course the outcome is typically the same if polygons are specified in the correct winding order, and the specified normals are actually the triangle normals. But in any case, testing each polygon separately on the CPU would be a total performance killer.